# Group by a custom value field wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have several posts with a custom field named "series". I want to group all posts by this custom field and below of this i want to list all posts which have not this custom field.

First i wanted to get grouped custom field value and then to be able to query again for all posts with this custom value key and value. But even trying to get the unique custom values does not work.

What i tried is this:

```
<?php
    function  query_group_by_filter($groupby){
       global $wpdb;

       return $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_key = "series"';
    }
?>

<?php add_filter('posts_groupby', 'query_group_by_filter'); ?>

<?php $states = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_key' => 'series',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
)); 
?>

<?php remove_filter('posts_groupby', 'query_group_by_filter'); ?>


<ul>
<?php
while ( $states->have_posts() ) : $states->the_post();

$mykey_values = get_post_custom_values( 'series' );

foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
    echo "<li>$key => $value ( 'series' )</li>"; 
}   

endwhile;
?>
</ul>
```

Whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

[WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

All posts with custom value:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'series',
            'value' => 'my-val',
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'series',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And without values:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'series',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! But the first part (query with values) is not what i am directly searching for. I need a group by custom field first. For example group by custom field 'series', lets assume that i have post with value 'Development Series' and 'Cloud Series' then i want to group by these two variable custom field values and then show below those groups the relevant posts.